# Flushing stream of ZIP

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to Flush a Zip file that has just been created, and have an issue with it:
a) it doesn't actually Flush (I used the code before with the CSV files and all works well)

Here is the code:

```
      outputMemStream.Position = 0;

      System.Web.HttpResponse Resp = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

      Resp.ClearContent();
      Resp.ClearHeaders();
      Resp.ContentType = "application/zip";
      Resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"download.zip\"");

      //byte[] buff = outputMemStream.ToArray();
      //File.WriteAllBytes(path, buff);

      outputMemStream.CopyTo(Resp.OutputStream);
      outputMemStream.Close();
      outputMemStream.Dispose();

      Resp.Flush();
      Resp.End();
```

The stream is created correctly because I am able to save it and can check it later that it looks alright.. just that thing that my browser doesn't allow me to download it is quite annoying.
Cheers for your help!

Comment: Is this in an aspx page, an ashx page, something else?

Comment: it's in the aspx page (in the code behind .cs), in one of the method that happens after pressing button "Export All"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's in the aspx page (in the code behind .cs), in one of the method
>   that happens after pressing button "Export All"

This is probably the issue.  The page is rendered both your file *and your controls* (including your "Export All" button).

Try moving the logic for downloading to a different page or handler that does nothing but return the file.

Comment: Hi, I thought that it's quite a silly idea but without any other I decided to give it a try and yes.. it worked! I created another empty page jsut with the method creating extract and it does work!